# Symfony 4.26 / php 7.4.9 - Could not find driver

Tags: php, symfony

I've got an issue, I can't create a simple controller using symfony.
I tried to do some work and create a new project.
It worked just fine but after that, I wanted to put a controller and go to the page :

> An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver

This is an error 500, I don't know how to fix it, I tried php -m to see the modules I got, and I DO have PDO.
I had a similar problem on another project, and I fixed it by putting a php.ini directly in my app folder, but it doesn't work on this new project, and I really want to fix this issue.

Also, I run my project with php 7.4.9 and symfony 4.26

the best track I have yet is only when I start the server with symfony server:start

> [OK] Web server listening
> The Web server is using PHP CGI 7.4.9
> https://127.0.0.1:8000

My server is running, and then :

```
[Application] Sep 29 10:51:20 |INFO   | REQUES Matched route "search_tool". method="GET" request_uri="https://127.0.0.1:8000/search/tool" route="search_tool" route_parameters={"_controller":"App\\Controller\\Searchontroller\\SearchToolController::index","_route":"search_tool"}
[Application] Sep 29 10:51:20 |DEBUG  | SECURI Checking for authenticator support. authenticators=0 firewall_name="main"
[Application] Sep 29 10:51:20 |DEBUG  | PHP    User Warning: Configure the "curl.cainfo", "openssl.cafile" or "openssl.capath" php.ini setting to enable the CurlHttpClient
[Application] Sep 29 10:51:20 |DEBUG  | PHP    User Notice: Upgrade the curl extension or run "composer require amphp/http-client" to perform async HTTP operations, including full HTTP/2 support   
[Application] Sep 29 10:51:20 |CRITICA| REQUES Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException: "An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver" at App\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Dctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 102
```

I have this problem since a few months, I always put php.ini in folders and it worked until this new project.

Also, the first message I have when I try to see my new controller is

```
Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\
DriverException
in App\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php (line 102)
```

I think this is a php / symfony issue, I tried to uninstall, upgrade them, but it's just the same.

Thank you for the help! :)

Comment: Please share more details. Which driver is missing? Are you sure you've installed everything needed for PostgreSQL?

Comment: I think this is "AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php", I don't know how to be sure?
And I don't even know what is PostgreSQL, I'm using WAMP / MySQL, I've never did this before, never touched PostgreSQL, and it's not in my extension, I've pgsql commented in my php.ini.

Isn't it the same as MySQL?

Comment: could you check the config in `config/packages/doctrine.yaml`. If you want to use mysql, you should see `pdo_mysql` in it

Comment: Then please share more details. How did you configure the database connection?